# Tree for 'unelectability'

Tags: linguistics

How would I go about making a derivational tree for this word? I am at a loss, I can't find the rules for making trees online and it is very confusing. I got that the stem is elect as a verb, then un-elect, then un-elect-able, and finally the full word un-elect-abl-ity. Is this the correct structure?

Comment: I find your question a bit broad and possibly off-topic in this site. Do you need a grammar to parse the english language?

Answer (score 0):

The correct assembly would be:

- elect+ABLE => electable (walk+ABLE => walkable)
- UN+electable => unelectable (UN+common => uncommon)
- unelectable+ITY => unelectability (acid+ITY => acidity)

Every step is motivated independently for simple derivations. UN+elect would mean impeach and your assembly would give something meaning impeachability.